# AngularJS - Defer function invokation till the full browser render and till the end of view-model synchronization cycle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm not sure what is the correct title for this question, so please correct me if I am wrong.

Let's say that on page refresh (load) I need to perform an **animated** scrolling to anchor according to the hash of current location (I know about ngAnchorScroll, but I need exectly an animated scolling, which ngAnchorScorll can't to do).

To do that I implemented a service, which will be called on controller initialization:

```
var Ctrl = function ($scope, initAnchorScrolling) {
    initAnchorScrolling($scope);
};

Ctrl.$inject = ['$scope', "initAnchorScrolling"];

applicationServices.factory("initAnchorScrolling",
    ['scroll', '$location', '$timeout', function(scrollUtils, $location, $timeout) {
    return function(scope) {

    /** Some stuff here */

    function scroll() {
        var hash = $location.hash(), elm;

        if (!hash) {
            scrollUtils.scrollTo(0, 0);
        } else if ((elm = getAnchorElement(hash))) {
            scrollUtils.scrollToElement(elm);
        } else {
            scrollUtils.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
    }

    scope.$watch(function scrollWatch() { return $location.hash(); },
        function scrollWatchAction() {
            $timeout(function () {
                scroll();
            }, 0, true);
        });
    };
}]);
```

You may see that this implementation of anchors is very similar to implementation of ngAnchorScroll. The main difference is that I'm using jQuery.animate() to move between anchors.

As I understood from [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/734#issuecomment-3657272) to defer function execution till the moment, when browser finished render, we just need to call $timeout service with a delay parameter, which equals to 0. But this is not working for me. Sporadically page scrolls to the different positions. I can explain it this way - scroll function invoked before digest cycle finished synchronization of views and models, so at the moment of invokation HTML blocks have invalid height and position.

So my question: is it possible to **defer function invokation till** the moment when browser **fully finished render and a digest cycle finished synchronization** of views and models (**applied bindings**)?

Comment: service is not meant for DOM manipulation. Use a directive, and try `scope.$on( '$routeChangeSuccess'..`  [$route docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$route)

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for suggestion, but what about the situation when page is just loaded or refreshed with a hash in URL? My question was not about the proper place for DOM manipulation.

Comment: play with `$routeChangeSuccess` in a controller... try this demo out  https://github.com/johnlindquist/angular-resolve/blob/master/client/js/app.js

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks again, but on case of big number of bindings (for example texts localizations) the $routeChangeSuccess event will be triggered before the end of digest cycle. So I will be not able to retrieve right information about elements positioning.

Comment: did you try `$timeout` in a directive? I've used that before to enable jqery isotope plugin which is very position dependent

Answer (score 0):

The original question is about scrolling to a particular hash while this solution is about retaining the scroll position no matter what.  Still it might give you a solution

i created a directive that works on the window scroll ( it could updated to work on any element though )

html usage

```
<div ng-keep-scroll="service.scrollY">
<!-- list of scrolling things here -->
</div>
```

where "service.scrollY" MUST be a variable within a service. Services retain their state and values, controllers are recreated every time they load and clear their values so you cant use them to store persistent data. the controller has a scope variable pointing to the service.

directive js

```
app.directive('ngKeepScroll', function ($timeout) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {

        //load scroll position after everything has rendered
        $timeout(function () {
            var scrollY = parseInt(scope.$eval(attrs.ngKeepScroll));
            $(window).scrollTop(scrollY ? scrollY : 0);
        }, 0);

        //save scroll position on change
        scope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function () {
            scope.$eval(attrs.ngKeepScroll + " = " + $(window).scrollTop());
        });
    }
});
```